# wget unable to download large directories completely

Tags: wget

wget works fine for downloading smaller directories. But it is unable to download directories that have many sub-folders and files in them. It doesn't throw any errors. But I can see that it has skipped several files.

This is the command I use:

```
wget -m -e robots=off -np -nH -R "index.html*" URL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Wget doesn't download directories, it follows links in HTML

If you have items that are not referred to in HTML, wget generally can't see them.